# ffmpeg -r / fps over time?

Tags: video, frame, timecodes

ok - going round in circles here so any help welcome...

using ffmpeg to generate frames from a movie. But i want to limit the total frames to 10 per movie.

So im trying to figure out the -r (fps) to use in the code.

So if the video is 10secs long i want 10 files which is -r 1 fps.

but if the video is 100 secs long and i want 10 files th -r should be 0.1 fps.

i just can't seem to figure out the formula?!

please help!

Comment: How do you know that that 10 frames is what you need? :)

Comment: its a variable: ie i want 10 frames for every video which creates an image sequence preview spanning the whole video length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok its `r = frameswanted / totalseconds`

Comment: HI. This actually means that I want `frameswanted`  at each `totalseconds` ?tks mate